# SQL injection vulnerability with order by clause in Java

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

Veracode report is showing a SQL injection flaw for the below query. There are few parameters which I need to get the property file and then need to inject into my SQL, i.e. schema name, sorting order, etc.

I tried to use the %s with String.format, but veraCode is still showing it as a flaw. For the parameter it is fine, since I used map, but for schema and sorting order, it's still showing a flaw.

Any approach to solve this vulnerability?

```
phoneLogsQuery = "(select * from %s.SHORETEL_EVENTS_CALL_LOGS where CONVERT( date, CallDateTime,112 ) >  CONVERT( date, GETDATE()-%s,112) "
                    + " and (CALLER_CONTACT_ID in (:contactId) or CALLED_CONTACT_ID in (:contactId)) and EXTERNAL_CALL = 1 "
                    + "UNION "
                    + "select * from %s.SHORETEL_EVENTS_CALL_LOGS where CONVERT( date, CallDateTime,112 ) >  CONVERT( date, GETDATE()-%s,112) "
                    + " and (CALLER_CONTACT_ID in (:contactId) or CALLED_CONTACT_ID in (:contactId))"
                    + " and GUILOGIN_NAME = :guiloginName and EXTERNAL_CALL = 0)"
                    + " order by CallDateTime %s %s ";
        
phoneLogsQuery = String.format(phoneLogsQuery, schemaname, phoneLogAllData, schemaname, phoneLogAllData, sortDir, offsetQuery);
shoretelPhoneLogRow = jdbcTemplate.query(phoneLogsQuery,params,
        new ShoretelPhoneLogMapper());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For column values you should use prepared statement. It makes injection impossible.Example  :

```
jdbcTemplate.query("Select * from user where id=?"), new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException
            {
                preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
            }
        }, new ResultSetExtractor<User>() {
...                
}});
```

Unfortunately, for column names, schema names, etc., you can use only concatenation or replace method:

```
"SELECT quantity from $tableName where event_id=?".replace("$tableName", "myTable")
```

The main thing that you should understand is that injection comes from end users and if those schema name, table name, etc., are inner info enduser can't change it. So you shouldn't be afraid of SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those values sadly cannot be interpolated by prepared statements, which means that you're going to have to do your own escaping. Not sure if Veracode is smart enough to detect it, but I'd go with `StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql` from apache commons lang

Answer (score 0):

Basic premise of fixing SQL injections is to not use your request object directly but by first sanitizing, validating and creating new objects / references (if needed), then fetching values from that sanitized object.

So, create a method to sanitize, validate & get values that you wish to append for your order by clause and use that value instead of directly from request.

An `append` with `StringBuilder` will be OK provided you don't directly take values from non-sanitized request.

In my opinion, you seem to getting your %s from request directly and that is why Veracode is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Use enum, it will resolve the issue. Enum limits the values you can pass to that parameter. Hence it will allow only given values. Even most of the security detection tools also consider this and will not report this as issue. If you do not want to expose column name, have different values in enum with constructore.

```
public class RequestDTO {

private SortOrder order;
private SortColumn colum;

}

public  enum SortOrder {
asc,
desc

}

public  enum SortColumn {
empployee_name
employee_department,
employee_salary

}
```